# Easiest way to get both text and images from a pdf file in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

I want to EXTRACT both the text and tbe images of a PDF file using PHP. All the libraries seem to be about reading, and most of the other solutions either only produce text, or only produce images, or is command line based. I'm looking for a complete solution in PHP. Is this possible?

At this point in time, I'm also open to other suggestions, such as perhaps there is a site with an API that you can submit the file to? Or perhaps someone can give instructions on a modern solution using the OpenOffice command line tool, of that's even possible?

Comment: (Even paid solutions are welcome?

Comment: I think PDFLib might help you!

Comment: Here, have a cookie: http://www.pdflib.com/download/ ;)

Do take a note that using PDFLib must require some practise before you're actually able to comprehand it!

Comment: that requires module installs etc. I want a pure php solution?

Comment: Wait, TET might do the trick...

Comment: Nevermind. Way too much effort. I want a simple php class or something?

Comment: hmm, fpdf might also work. But I am not sure if you can read PDF using it. LINK: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: I'm absolutely shocked there is no library that can read PHP. I always figured that to be an extremely simple requirement...

Answer (score 0):

What about the Google Docs API? They have an OCR that you might be able to work with.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_using_optical_character_recognition_ocr